# "looping" and subsetting list elements in R

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a list of vectors in an R list, such that each position of the list contains 3 columns, e.g:

```
d[[1]]
   lon lat pr
1 -70  10  0
2 -70   9  0
3 -70   8  0
4 -70   7  0
5 -70   6  0
6 -70   5  0

d[[2]]
   lon lat   pr
1 -70  10 0.48
2 -70   9 0.00
3 -70   8 0.00
4 -70   7 0.00
5 -70   6 0.00
6 -70   5 0.16
```

and so on...

I want to get all say 1st, 3rd and 6th positions of all vectors in list and to store it in another list or data frame, e.g

```
list[[1]]
   lon lat pr
1 -70  10  0
3 -70   8  0
6 -70   5  0

list[[2]]
   lon lat pr
1 -70  10 0.48
3 -70   8 0.00
6 -70   5 0.16
```

etc...

I tried some lapply and derivates without success. Is there a more straightforward way of doing it other than looping through all indexes values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply`

```
> lapply(mylist, function(x) x[c(1,3,6),])
[[1]]
  lon lat pr
1 -70  10  0
3 -70   8  0
6 -70   5  0

[[2]]
  lon lat   pr
1 -70  10 0.48
3 -70   8 0.00
6 -70   5 0.16
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thx a lot @Jilber!